# *** KeyError: 'font-family' on replacing a html string into another html string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to read 2 html files, and one to another in python, but I'm getting this error:

```
*** KeyError: '                font-family'
```

This is my code:

```
with open ("/.../email-template.html", "r") as myfile:
        html_content=myfile.read().replace("\n", "")

with open ("/.../product_info.html", "r") as myfile:
        product_info=myfile.read().replace("\n", "")

html_content.format(products=product_info)
```

This is email-template.html that part that should be replaced:

```
...
<table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">

                {{products}}

                <!-- Clear Spacer : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="40" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Error comes from css: string = "{{0}} {font-family: sans-serif}"
string = string.format("foo")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given templates is not meant to be used with `str.format` (where `{...}` used for formatting). It seems like Django template or Jinja template (considering it's using `{{...}}` for replacement).

Using jinja:

```
with open (".../email-template.html", "r") as myfile:
    html_content = myfile.read()  # removed `replace` to preserve newline

with open (".../product_info.html", "r") as myfile:
    product_info = myfile.read().replace("\n", "")

import jinja2
formatted = jinja2.Template(html_content).render(products=product_info)
```